# Whether program is executed from command line or invoked through system call

Tags: linux, command-line, executable, invoke, system-calls

Platform is linux and the `c` code is compiled in gcc.

Is it possible to know from inside the code of program  whether its executable has been executed directly from *command line* or invoked through "`system`" call ?
e.g `test.exe` can be directly run on command line as `./test.exe` or executed through `system("/home/mydir/test.exe")` How do I know inside the running program as to how it was invoked ?

Comment: Command line interpreter uses _system call_ to run a program, there is no difference from a view of an OS.

Comment: Moreover, `system(...)` runs command-line interpreter in non-interactive mode, so there is not much difference too.

Comment: So that sounds its not possible to decipher @myaut

Comment: you may modify kernel so it'll save userspace stack in `execve` system call, but it is very complex to implement.

Comment: Assuming it's your calling code, you could use a special command line switch to tell the program it's being called via system, e.g. `system("/home/mydir/test.exe -s")`.

Comment: Thanks @Paul ! I liked your simple suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it simply can be found by parsing `argv[0]` from `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. If it contains `/`, it is called from its path, otherwise it is called from command-line.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to tell for sure, since at the end of the day you end up doing execve. You can employ some weird heuristics like checking parent processes, but that's all crap.

The real question is why would you care, or: what is the *actual* problem?

If that system() consumer is supposed to do something differently, have it either pass a special argument or set a special environment variable passed to that process.